# Dates in R differ between Windows and Linux

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a data frame in R names as data.

```
data <- as.xts(read.zoo("data1.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T))
```

data index in the format `2004-01-04 09:44:00 IST`

I applied the operation to change the index to Dates

```
index(data) <- as.Date(index(data))
```

Output should be `2004-01-04` but system produces `2004-01-03`.

This works correctly in Windows but does not work on Linux.

Comment: Date                          Open Low High Close 
2010-01-04 09:04:00 5222.9 5224.6 5220.1 5220.35
2010-01-04 09:05:00 5220.2 5222.95 5218.6 5222.95      index(data) <- as.Date(index(data)) . If I type index(date)[1] on the command prompt it gives 2010-01-03 rather than 2010-01-04

Comment: data.csv files contain data in the format    Date,Open,Low,High,Close
2010-01-04 09:04:00,5222.9,5224.6,5220.1,5220.35
2010-01-04 09:05:00,5220.2,5222.95,5218.6,5222.95
2010-01-04 09:06:00,5222.25,5225,5222.25,5225
2010-01-04 09:07:00,5225,5225.9,5219.4,5219.4                       data <- as.xts(read.zoo("data1.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T)) index(data) <- as.Date(index(data)) . Index of data it gives as "2010-01-03"

Answer (score 3):

Arun is correct that the problem is with locale.  Your data has an Indian Standard Time stamp, and you have a US locale, which is at least 10.5 hours behind.  Hence the time `09:44` is actually late the previous evening in your time zone.

Dates and time are horribly complicated, and R uses underlying OS capabilities to make it's calculations, which is why you see different results on different machines.  Linux is POSIX compliant and understands time zones like "IST", which allows it to make the change to the previous night.  Windows does not, which is why it gives the date as `01-04`.  To get the correct time zone update on Windows, you need to specify the full name of the time zone, "Asia/Kolkata".  Wikipedia has a [list of time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

---

EDIT: Actually, R ships with a file containing all the "Continent/City" (Olson-style) names that it accepts.  It is stored in

```
file.path(R.home("share"), "zoneinfo", "zone.tab")
```

and the example on the help page `?Sys.timezone` tells you how to programmatically read it.

---

I find the `lubridate` package makes things a little easier to see what is happening.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd_hms("2004-01-04 09:44:00 IST", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
x
# [1] "2004-01-04 09:44:00 IST"
with_tz(x, "America/New_York")
# [1] "2004-01-03 23:14:00 EST"
```

Comment: if I run the command as.Date(data) it gives correct date even in Linux. class(Index(data)) is POSIXct. When I change POSIXct to date object by using index(data) <- as.Date(index(data)) then it store the previous day date in index(data)

Answer (score 1):

```
Date <- c("2010-01-04 09:04:00", "2010-01-04 09:05:00")
Open <- c(5222.9, 5220.2)
Low <- c(5224.6, 5222.95)
High <- c(5220.1, 5218.6)
Close <- c(5220.35, 5222.95)
x <- data.frame(Date = Date, Open = Open, Low = Low, High = High, Close = Close)
as.Date(x$Date)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2010-01-04" "2010-01-04"
```

It seems alright to me.

`Edit:`

```
require(zoo)
data <- as.xts(read.zoo("data1.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T))
> dput(data)

structure(c(5222.9, 5220.2, 5224.6, 5222.95, 5220.1, 5218.6, 
5220.35, 5222.95), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
"Low", "High", "Close")), index = structure(c(1262592240, 1262592300
), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")

> as.Date(index(data))

[1] "2010-01-04" "2010-01-04"
```

On my Mac it works right. I suspect your system locale is set wrong. Also, you may want to check it within R.

What does this command `Sys.getlocale()` give you in `Windows` and in `Linux` within `R`?

Comment: First change this data frame to time series by using below command   data <- as.xts(read.zoo("data1.csv",sep=",",tz="" ,header=T)) here index(data) produce "2010-01-04" "2010-01-04" then do                 index(data) <- as.Date(index(data)) here is gives output as  "2010-01-03" "2010-01-03". This problem occurs in linux only. Same code works on window.

Comment: What do you mean by locale and How to check  that. I checked date() in linux and window and it gives current time and date

Comment: Checked everything.ALl local settings are correct. There is some other problem

Comment: Sys.getlocale() in window gives: "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
in Linux gives:  "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Comment: Problem not sorted out yet. Any other idea